# How to save ios object or view parameters to server?

Tags: mysql, ios, calayer, object-properties

What is the best way to save object parameters to DB in ios? => like sending values to server application and server will save the parameters to db? And later that ios-app will get the properties and create the new object again.

What is the best way to do it? For ex, saving `CALayer` or `UIImageView` attributes like size, position, color, border width etc..

Comment: if you are sending some data to server, why do you want to save it locally?

Comment: Why do you want to send size/position/color...etc., of UIImageView to server? Thats a pretty strange requirement.

Comment: @bhargavg Users will create some designs with views and i need to save these designs for future use.

Comment: @hackerinheels for now i don't need to save properties to local. But later, offline app using is being necessary, i will also save same properties to local db inside the ios device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a data model which defines what this data looks like.

Once you have it, you will need to define some sort of REST api against your server to get/post/put/delete this data. 
To implement this network layer you can look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) are other useful libs to consider

To store locally you can look at CoreData - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Comment: What do you think about the data model? Is this the best way => creating nsdictionary for each object/view/image. converting nsdict to json and sending to server with AFNetworking.?? Also there will be a lot of properties. Do you think saving 1 varible to 1 column in db is good db mapping?